# Why doesn't Lombok Builder work with mutating an existing object?

Tags: lombok, builder

Why doesn't Lombok Builder work with mutating an existing object?

What if I want to create a partially build object, and then later on update the object with the remaining fields?

Notice that this is not working.  The pre-compiler doesn't like what I am trying to do.

[image]

Code Provided:

```
private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

{
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
}
@Test
public void testBuilderMutating() throws JsonProcessingException {
    Book unfinishedBook = Book.builder()
            .isbn(String.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID()))
            .title("Title")
            .genre("Science Fiction")
            .author("me")
            .published(LocalDateTime.now())
            .description("description ...")
            .build();
    Book completedBook = rebuildBook(unfinishedBook)
            .sectionCount(4)
            .sectionNames(List.of("A", "B", "C"))
            .chapterCount(16)
            .chapterNames(List.of("1", "2", "3"))
            .build();
    log.info(objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(completedBook));
}

public Book.BookBuilder rebuildBook(Book unfinished) {
    return Book.builder()
            .isbn(unfinished.getIsbn())
            .title(unfinished.getTitle())
            .genre(unfinished.getGenre())
            .author(unfinished.getAuthor())
            .published(unfinished.getPublished())
            .description(unfinished.getDescription())
            .sectionCount(unfinished.getSectionCount())
            .sectionNames(unfinished.getSectionNames())
            .chapterCount(unfinished.getChapterCount())
            .chapterNames(unfinished.getChapterNames());
}
```

POJOs are:

```
@ToString
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
public class Chapters extends Sections {
    private int chapterCount;
    private List<String> chapterNames;
}

@ToString
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
public class Sections {
    private int sectionCount;
    private List<String> sectionNames;
}

@ToString
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
public class Book extends Chapters {
    private String isbn;
    private String title;
    private String genre;
    private String author;
    private LocalDateTime published;
    private String description;
}
```

Comment: Side remark: You should think about using `toBuilder()` in your `rebuildBook` method (by `@SuperBuilder(toBuilder=true)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because `@SuperBuilder` is defined as `BookBuilder<?, ?>` and java could not infer type if raw type is used `Book.BookBuilder`. To fix it change definition to

```
public Book.BookBuilder<?, ?> rebuildBook(Book unfinished) {
   ...
```

Also, to have correct implementation of `toString` and `equals` you need to use `callSuper = true`.

In addition, having `@NoArgsConstructor`, `@AllArgsConstructor`, `@SuperBuilder` and `@Data` looks a little too much. There is a way to define immutable POJO with Lombok and be able to deserialize using builder by applying `@Jacksonized` annotation.

```
@Getter
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Jacksonized
@SuperBuilder
public class Chapters extends Sections {
    private int chapterCount;
    private List<String> chapterNames;
}

@Getter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Jacksonized
@SuperBuilder
public class Sections {
    private int sectionCount;
    private List<String> sectionNames;
}

@Getter
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Jacksonized
@SuperBuilder
public class Book extends Chapters {
    private String isbn;
    private String title;
    private String genre;
    private String author;
    private LocalDateTime published;
    private String description;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  That was it.  In retrospect, intellisense probably would have told me that.  Thanks so much.   Thanks for the additional tip as well.